# getAttribute not returning the value I was expecting

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to make a flashcard type of web app. Each question is in an `h2` and each answer is in a `p`. I want the answer to initially be hidden and to be revealed when a user clicks the question `h2`, so I added a `data-question-obj-id="{{question.id}}"` (django project, `{{question.id}}` evaluates to positive integer so 1,2,3,etc) attribute to both to know which question is associated with which answer. However, I am struggling to get the data-attribute portion to work:

Say I had the following html:

```
  <h2 data-question-obj-id="1">What is Diffusion?</h2> 
  <p data-question-obj-id="1">Spontaneous movement of particles...</p>
  <h2 data-question-obj-id="2">What is Osmosis?</h2> 
  <p data-question-obj-id="2">Spontaneous passage or diffusion of water or...</p>
```

In my js, I am attempting to get all questions then loop through them and add a click event to each one that logs the clicked questions `data-question-obj-id` attribute value to the console, but it is logging the same attribute value for every question:

```
questions = document.querySelectorAll('h2[data-question-obj-id]');

for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  question = questions[i];
  console.log(question); // Sanity check, outputs <h2 data-question-obj-id="1">Diffusion</h2> then <h2 data-question-obj-id="2">Osmosis</h2> as expected
  question.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(question.getAttribute("data-question-obj-id")); // Will output '2' not matter what question is clicked
  });
```

}

For brevity I only included two question/answer combinations but if I had three, that `console.log(question.getAttribute("data-question-obj-id"));` would output `3` for any question clicked, so it seems to always be getting the value of the last element? Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Declare question as const or let in the loop

Comment: Otherwise it’s a global

Comment: ^^ in other words the LAST question

Comment: Also take advantage of [the `.dataset` API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: `e.target.nextElementSibling` from within the listener would give you the related `p` for the clicked `h2` without any ids, assuming the p always immediately follows the h2.

Comment: @DanielA.White this was driving me nuts. Thanks.

Comment: Probably want to brush up on [JavaScript closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can preload the answers too and when you loop the questions with your index, you can use the index to infer the corresponding answer too. I have made sure the answer is initially hidden and clicking on the question toggles the appearance of the answer.

```js
let questions = document.querySelectorAll('h2[data-question-obj-id]');
let answers = document.querySelectorAll('p[data-question-obj-id]');

for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  let question = questions[i];
  let answer = answers[i]
  question.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(question.getAttribute("data-question-obj-id")); // Will output '2' not matter what question is clicked
    answer.classList[(answer.classList.contains('invisible') ? 'remove' : 'add')]('invisible');
  });
}
```

```css
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
  <h2 data-question-obj-id="1">What is Diffusion?</h2> 
  <p data-question-obj-id="1" class="invisible">Spontaneous movement of particles...</p>
  <h2 data-question-obj-id="2">What is Osmosis?</h2> 
  <p data-question-obj-id="2" class="invisible">Spontaneous passage or diffusion of water or...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach (in vanilla ecmascript).

First: wrap question and answer within a `div` containing the `obj-question-id` data attribute. Second: use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle any question with a single handler function (identifying the question ID using [`[event.target].closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)).

For displaying the question on mousedown, I used [nested css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting) in the snippet.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const questionBlock = evt.target.closest(`[data-question-obj-id]`);
  
  if (questionBlock) {
    console.clear();
    return console.log(`[data-question-obj-id] = ${
      questionBlock.dataset.questionObjId}`);
  }
}
```

```css
div[data-question-obj-id] {
  h2 { margin: 0.2em; }
  div { display: none; }
  &:active {
    div {
      display: block;
      color: #777;
      margin-left: 2em;
    }
  }
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div data-question-obj-id="1"> 
  <h2>What is Diffusion?</h2>
  <div>Spontaneous movement of particles...</div>
</div>
<div data-question-obj-id="2"> 
  <h2 >What is Osmosis?</h2>
  <div>Spontaneous passage or diffusion of water or...</div>
</div>
```